# Jackson still complains about missing filter id / skip missing filters

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a ObjectMapper like so:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

// ignore missing filters
mapper.setFilters(new SimpleFilterProvider().setFailOnUnknownId(false));

// add module for meta data permissions
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("IncludeMetaData", new Version(0, 1, 0, "alpha"));
module.addSerializer(MetaClass.class, new MetaDataSerializer(permissions, p instanceof AbstractBean ? ((AbstractBean) p).isOwner() : false));
mapper.registerModule(module);

return mapper.writerWithView(Views.Admin.class).writeValueAsString(p)
```

But when I serialize jackson still complains about missing filter id and fails. How can I ingonre missing filters for specific mappers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beleve it or not, you have to set the filters after the modules

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

// add module for meta data permissions
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("IncludeMetaData", new Version(0, 1, 0, "alpha"));
module.addSerializer(MetaClass.class, new MetaDataSerializer(permissions, p instanceof AbstractBean ? ((AbstractBean) p).isOwner() : false));
mapper.registerModule(module);

// ignore missing filters
mapper.setFilters(new SimpleFilterProvider().setFailOnUnknownId(false));

return mapper.writerWithView(Views.Admin.class).writeValueAsString(p)
```

Comment: Is there any way this can be incorporated for the JacksonFeature for jersey?